# When do I use solrindex [-filter] and [-normalize]?

Tags: nutch

In the Nutch wiki it suggests use of the following:

```
bin/nutch solrindex <solr url> <crawldb> [-linkdb <linkdb>] [-params k1=v1&k2=v2...] (<segment> ... | -dir <segments>) [-noCommit] [-deleteGone] [-filter] [-normalize]
```

What is the purpose of

```
[-filter] [-normalize]
```

when Nutch has numerous filter and normalization configuration files?

```
automaton-urlfilter.txt
domain-urlfilter.txt
regex-urlfilter.txt
suffix-urlfilter.txt
regex-normalize.xml
host-urlnormalizer.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

When indexing to Solr these config files are set to false by default, so if you wish the indexes you are passing to Solr to be normalized or filetered then you would enable these options.

To me it seems like a pointless option but only because that is not how I would like my configuration of Solr to work, but it is a more advanced feature that will benefit a small amount of people

Comment: So, you're saying that [-filter] [-normalize] are additional/optional configurations to the 6 files I mentioned above?

Comment: So if you were to use the -filter flag it would apply the 4 filtering config files.  If you were  to apply the -normalize flag it would normalize them using the 2 normalize config files